# header(location) on form does not work after submit button clicked

Tags: php, html

This is my code for my submit button. Once data submitted to mysql i want it to redirect to page.html.

```
<form name="gender."; action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
```

I have added

```
     <?php 
      header("location:page.html");     
    exit; } 
<?
```

to the very top of my form page. However it just loads page.html rather loading after submit button is clicked.

Comment: also, what's with the semicolon in the form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Please don't use `PHP_SELF`, it is vulnerable to exploitation. If you want the action to be the same page, just leave it empty.

2) The `header()`, which I assume is at the top of the page since it works, has no control on it.

**EDIT1**: Expanding based on question in comment below.

3) The `header()`  directive will forward the browser to the new page and stop any further processing. Because of this, all the MySQL processing should be complete before redirecting.

4) The `$_POST` array gets the key names from the `name` attribute of the inputs, so be sure that your `<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" ...` matches the `$_POST['submitbtn']`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // MySQL stuff goes here
    header("Location: page.html");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: ok i changed <form name="gender."; action="" method="post" >   .... I added your script to the top of the page with no white spaces. result: the page loaded with the form on it but when submitted it did not submit to mysql nor did it go onto page.html. :s

Comment: for that you would need to show us what exactly you are doing with the post data. Could you update your question with the entire contents of your php post handling?

Comment: Why is there a `;` in your form tag? Or a `.` in the name attribute? Regardless, the MySQL stuff needs to go between the `if(isset(...` and the `header()` if you want it to be properly handled. As for why it didn't redirect, the submit button should be as follows: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` or something similar. The important part is the `name="submit"` which is sent to `$_POST` as the key name.

Comment: my code is here: http://pastebin.com/d6h2gnLa . an updated version with correct code would be great

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/0Etn46HV I left you a few comments. Also, make sure to put your SQL statements in the right place, and read up on SQL Injection. connection.inc isn't available to me, so I can't see your connection mechanism, but I assume you used `mysql_connect()`. This is highly insecure and I suggest you read up on PDO, or at least use mysqli.

Comment: ill give that a go now. thnx. You have removed $sql = "UPDATE user SET attendance1 ................. I need these to update the mysql fields..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy them over, but just use the ones you had before and paste them where it says `// EVERY SINGLE UPDATE SQL QUERY GOES HERE`

Comment: ok at first I left them were they weere and the mysql updated and did not redirect to page.html. I then moved them up and mysql did not update nor did it redirect to page.html .. http://pastebin.com/jWVa7Z3i

Comment: Did you remember to match the name of the submit button to the referenced key in `$_POST`? See #4 above

Comment: ahhhh you are amazing thanks soo much ive been trying to do that for weeks :). one more question whilst we are on the topic which i would like you to help me with then my project is complete. I would like to make another page that if someone has already entered their data it redirect them to a page where it says 'sorry you have already made your selection'. The easiest field would be attendance1 where the value is either a 'Yes' or a 'No' so if it is either one of these values it will redirect to the page i want.

Comment: @Grexis .. please help me for the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169676/php-code-to-redirect-if-mysql-field-is-complete

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to add the condition before header to check if data is submitted or not.
eg:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnname'])
{header("location:page.html");
exit; // this is unnecessary
}
```

Also, if you want to use form for submission, you'll need to post it on page.php. 
as this code will redirect the page without saving the form's data anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

My main suspect is that your PHP is set up to suppress warnings and errors. Turn them on in the php.ini file and see what the message is.

Most likely it will say something along the line like "html headers cannot be sent as there is already output in line so and so..."

The PHP hear function cannot work if there is any output already echoed from the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['button'])){

  header('Location:page.html');
  exit;

}



?>
```

Can you modify the code like this ?